# Why does Firefox mess up page loading if I use a cache manifest?

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, html

I have developed an html5 game which I also want to play offline, so I decided to add a manifest file.

The game is in a subdirectory, e.g. /games/game/ and the manifest is in that directory: /games/game/application.manifest. But the game depends on serval site-common files stored in /js and /css OUTSIDE the game directory!!! The whole game is cached; all paths are in the manifest file, even those of site-common files. When I want to access the site with firefox, everything looks pretty. When I reload the page, serval files (including one IMPORTANT js file and some images) are not included / displayed in the page, the game - of course - doesn't work. The missing files are all outside of /games/game, e.g. in /img or /js. BUT THEY're cached!!! If I go to offline mode and type the URL of one, firefox displays me the contents! WTF, what am I missing?

Here the game:
nocore.info/games/minesweeper/

Manifest:
nocore.info/games/minesweeper/application.manifest

Not loaded javascript file (minified):
nocore.info/js/common.js

Not loaded images:
nocore.info/img/share/*.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may find an answer in this thread: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2011/3/10/Frustrating-issues-with-Firefox-and-offline-manifests